# What can I do, when I find a question that fits to my problem, but the answer is not explicit enough for me?

Tags: support

Current example

[How to do networking between virtual machines in VirtualBox?](https://superuser.com/questions/119732/how-to-do-networking-between-virtual-machines-in-virtualbox)

It describes exactly my current problem, but the answers do not help me.

I would like more specific and complete instructions, how to set up the network adapters in such an environment.

What is the prefer way to behave in such cases?

Comment: start a bounty? The tooltip says "offer some of your reputation for better answers"

Comment: You can also post comment on  the answers, asking them for different angle. They might choose to edit their answer with extra details that you need.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try the [Virtual Networking Guide](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) that [mpygon posted](https://superuser.com/questions/119732/how-to-do-networking-between-virtual-machines-in-virtualbox/119741#119741)?

Users of SE are expected to show research effort on their questions.  If the Virtual Networking guide didn't work out for you, try posting a specific question about where you're stuck.

Comment: The Virtual Networking Guide is a ridiculous article for those using VirtualBox under Windows. What is needed is a clear note "Sorry guys you can't configure DHCP by GUI you have to use the command line here. What I miss are links which describe the network setup by GUI. What I hear is RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

Start a bounty, and add a comment saying that you've added a bounty saying what you want an answer to tell you, or saying what is missing in the existing answers.

Users with low reputation should be careful with the amount of bounty they set!

Answer (score 0):

I think another option would be to ask specialized questions. E.g.

```
How to do networking between virtual machines in VirtualBox using internal networking
```

That case was mentioned in the accepted answer, but the OP told, that it didn't work for him.