# Can I ask a duplicate question because the asker's accepted answer is unacceptable to me?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking about this question in particular: [Is it ever acceptable to have multiple IDs in a html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774762/is-it-ever-acceptable-to-have-multiple-ids-in-a-html-page)

I don't want to re-ask the question and have it closed, but this question won't get any more traffic seeing as it has an accepted answer and was asked a year ago.  What should I do?

Note: **This** is a close duplicate of [What can I do, when I find a question that fits to my problem, but the answer is not explicit enough for me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107299/what-can-i-do-when-i-find-a-question-that-fits-to-my-problem-but-the-answer-is) , but slightly different.  My question was asked perfectly, yet the answer is accepted and I don't find it acceptable.  I would have asked what to do in this case, but there was no metameta.stackoverflow.com. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered adding a [bounty to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty)? You can add anywhere from 50 to 500 (in steps of 50) of your own reputation as a bounty to attract better answers.

A [recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103956/how-should-bounties-be-categorized) also lets you add your own reasons to let others know why you've placed the bounty.

So in your case, you would choose either "Current answers are outdated" or "Improve details" and later add additional info on the next page, as to *how* you want the answer improved (or other details you're looking for).

[image]

Comment: And, of course, you can now add bounty reasons, too!

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize that I could add a bounty to a question with an accepted answer!  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can ask another *similar* question - if it is identical then you should mention in your question why the original doesn't suit your purpose (which co-incidentally makes your question no longer identical).

You could also add a bounty to the original question, which may or may not achieve what you are asking.